# Crawling all page with scrapy and FormRequest

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I would like to scrape all link for the formation in this website : https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/

Apparently the next pages are dynamically loaded with AJAX. I need to simulate those requests using FormRequest from scrapy.

That was I did, I look up for the parameters with developer tools : [ajax1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3knzx.png)

I put those parameters into `FormRequest` but apparently if it didn't work, I need to include the header, that what I did : [ajax2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErYr1.png)

But it didn't work either.. I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong but what ?

Here's my script, if you want (sorry it's quite long, because I put all the parameters and the headers) :

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from lxml import html
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

class LinkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "link"
    #allow_domains = ['https://www.formatic-centre.fr/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/']

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'formation'), callback="parse", follow= True),)

    def parse(self, response):
        card = response.xpath('//a[@class="title"]')
        for a in card:
            yield {'links': a.xpath('@href').get()}

        return [FormRequest(url="https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/",
            formdata={'action' :    "swlabscore",
                        'module[0]' : "top.Top_Controller",
                        'module[1]' : "ajax_get_course_pagination",
                        'page' :    "2",
                        'layout' :  "course",
                        'limit_post' :  "",
                        'offset_post' : "0",
                        'sort_by' : "",
                        'pagination' :  "yes",
                        'location_slug' :   "",
                        'columns' : "2",
                        'paged' :   "",
                        'cur_limit' :   "",
                        'rows': "0",
                        'btn_content' : "En+savoir+plus",
                        'uniq_id' : "block-13759488265f916bca45c89",
                        'ZmfUNQ': "63y[Jt",
                        'PmhpIuZ_cTnUxqg' : "7v@IahmJNMplbCu",
                        'cZWVDbSPzTXRe' : "n9oa2k5u4GHWm",
                        'eOBITfdGRuriQ' :   "hBPN5nObe.ktH",
                        "Accept" : "*/*",
                        "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip, deflate, br",
                        "Accept-Language" : "fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
                        "Connection" : "keep-alive",
                        "Content-Length" : "1010",
                        "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                        "Cookie" : "_ga=GA1.2.815964309.1603392091; _gid=GA1.2.1686929506.1603392091; jlFYkafUWiyJe=LGAWcXg_wUjFo; z-byDgTnkdcQJSNH=03d1yiqH%40h8uZNtw; YeAhrFumyo-HQwpn=5uOhD6viWy%5BYeq3o",
                        "Host" : "www.formatic-centre.fr",
                        "Origin" : "https://www.formatic-centre.fr",
                        "Referer" : "https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/",
                        "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0",
                        "X-Requested-With" : "XMLHttpRequest",
                        "access-control-allow-credentials" : "true",
                        "access-control-allow-origin" : "https://www.formatic-centre.fr",
                        "cache-control" : "no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0",
                        "content-encoding": "gzip",
                        "content-length" :"2497",
                        "content-type" :"text/html; charset=UTF-8",
                        "date" :"Thu, 22 Oct 2020 18:42:54 GMT",
                        "expires" :"Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT",
                        "referrer-policy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
                        "server": "Apache",
                        "set-cookie" : "jlFYkafUWiyJe=LGAWcXg_wUjFo; expires=Fri, 23-Oct-2020 18:42:54 GMT; Max-Age=86400; path=/; secure",
                        "set-cookie" : "z-byDgTnkdcQJSNH=03d1yiqH%40h8uZNtw; expires=Fri, 23-Oct-2020 18:42:54 GMT; Max-Age=86400; path=/; secure",
                        "set-cookie" : "YeAhrFumyo-HQwpn=5uOhD6viWy%5BYeq3o; expires=Fri, 23-Oct-2020 18:42:54 GMT; Max-Age=86400; path=/; secure",
                        "strict-transport-security" : "max-age=15552001; preload",
                        "vary" : "Accept-Encoding",
                        "x-content-type-options" : "nosniff",
                        "X-Firefox-Spdy" : "h2",
                        "x-frame-options" : "SAMEORIGIN",
                        "x-robots-tag" : "noindex"})]
```

The script work for the first page, I obtained the links, but when he need to use FormRequest, nothing happened and I can't obtained the link in the next pages.

Any ideas ?

EDIT : I didn't see it but the terminal tell me this error :

```
2020-10-23 03:51:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/> (referer: https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/) ['partial']
2020-10-23 03:51:30 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

Maybe it could help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues with how you format and send both your `headers` and the `payload` itself.

Also, you have to keep changing the page, so the server knows where you're at and what response to send back.

I didn't want to set up a new `scrapy` project but here's how I got all the links, so hopefully this will nudge you in the right direction:

And if it feels like a hack, well, because it is one.

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "origin": "https://www.formatic-centre.fr",
    "referer": "https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.99 Safari/537.36",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
}

raw_string = "action=swlabscore&module%5B%5D=top.Top_Controller&module%5B%5D=ajax_get_course_pagination&params%5B0%5D%5Bpage%5D=2&params%5B0%5D%5Batts%5D%5Blayout%5D=course&params%5B0%5D%5Batts%5D%5Blimit_post%5D=&params%5B0%5D%5Batts%5D%5Boffset_post%5D=0&params%5B0%5D%5Batts%5D%5Bsort_by%5D=&params%5B0%5D%5Batts%5D%5Bpagination%5D=yes&params%5B0%5D%5Batts%5D%5Blocation_slug%5D=&params%5B0%5D%5Batts%5D%5Bcolumns%5D=2&params%5B0%5D%5Batts%5D%5Bpaged%5D=&params%5B0%5D%5Batts%5D%5Bcur_limit%5D=&params%5B0%5D%5Batts%5D%5Brows%5D=0&params%5B0%5D%5Batts%5D%5Bbtn_content%5D=En+savoir+plus&params%5B0%5D%5Batts%5D%5Buniq_id%5D=block-13759488265f916bca45c89&params%5B0%5D%5Batts%5D%5Bthumb-size%5D%5Blarge%5D=swedugate-thumb-300x225&params%5B0%5D%5Batts%5D%5Bthumb-size%5D%5Bno-image%5D=thumb-300x225.gif&params%5B0%5D%5Batts%5D%5Bthumb-size%5D%5Bsmall%5D=swedugate-thumb-300x225&params%5B0%5D%5Blayout_course%5D=style-grid&ZmfUNQ=63y[Jt&PmhpIuZ_cTnUxqg=7v@IahmJNMplbCu&cZWVDbSPzTXRe=n9oa2k5u4GHWm&eOBITfdGRuriQ=hBPN5nObe.ktH"

payloadd = [
    ('action', 'swlabscore'),
    ('module[]', 'top.Top_Controller'),
    ('module[]', 'ajax_get_course_pagination'),
    ('params[0][page]', '1'),
    ('params[0][atts][layout]', 'course'),
    ('params[0][atts][offset_post]', '0'),
    ('params[0][atts][pagination]', 'yes'),
    ('params[0][atts][columns]', '2'),
    ('params[0][atts][rows]', '0'),
    ('params[0][atts][btn_content]', 'En savoir plus'),
    ('params[0][atts][uniq_id]', 'block-13759488265f916bca45c89'),
    ('params[0][atts][thumb-size][large]', 'swedugate-thumb-300x225'),
    ('params[0][atts][thumb-size][no-image]', 'thumb-300x225.gif'),
    ('params[0][atts][thumb-size][small]', 'swedugate-thumb-300x225'),
    ('params[0][layout_course]', 'style-grid'),
    ('ZmfUNQ', '63y[Jt'),
    ('PmhpIuZ_cTnUxqg', '7v@IahmJNMplbCu'),
    ('cZWVDbSPzTXRe', 'n9oa2k5u4GHWm'),
    ('eOBITfdGRuriQ', 'hBPN5nObe.ktH'),
]

all_links = []
for page in range(1, 10):
    payloadd.pop(3)
    payloadd.insert(3, ('params[0][page]', str(page)))
    response = requests.post(
        "https://www.formatic-centre.fr/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?",
        headers=headers,
        data=urlencode(payloadd)
    )
    print(f"Getting links from page {page}...")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser").find_all("a", class_="btn btn-green")
    links = [i["href"] for i in soup]
    print('\n'.join(links))
    all_links.extend(links)


with open("formatic-center_links.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines("\n".join(all_links) + "\n")
```

This produces a file with all the links under the `EN SAVOIR PLUS` buttons.

```
https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/les-regles-juridiques-du-teletravail/
https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/mieux-gerer-son-stress-en-periode-du-covid-19/
https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/dynamiser-vos-equipes-special-post-confinement/
https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/conduire-ses-entretiens-specifique-post-confinement/
https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/cours-excel/
https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/autocad-3d-2/
https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/concevoir-et-developper-une-strategie-marketing/
https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/preparer-soutenance/
https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/mettre-en-place-une-campagne-adwords/
https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/utiliser-google-analytics/
and so on ...
```

Comment: Wow, what a nice answer, I will check it out, I keep you in touch. :) Many thanks

Comment: That work like a charm, nice job ! Just out of curiosity, It was not doable with scrapy ? And do you think this script could be reusable for other websites ? If we assume the website is dynamically loaded with AJAX and we change the headers and so on of course.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not that familiar with `scrapy` but I'm sure this can be done with it too. If you find the answer useful, please accept it and/or up-vote.

Comment: upvoted and accepted :)   And do you think this script could be reusable for other websites ? If we assume the website is dynamically loaded with AJAX and we change the headers and so on of course.

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure. Best to work with AJAX case by case.

Comment: What do you mean ? Wait and see ? I feel like each problem is unique and we need to adapt our code to each website. That's tedious.

Comment: Well, welcome to the world of web scraping. Sure, at times it can get tedious, but each web site *is* different, so you have to adapt.